# Discord.py certificate verify failed:

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have a discord bot that works through my computer but when I run it on my vps on debien 10, I get this error:

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl: True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c: 1056)')]
```

I have no idea where this problem comes from.
I have already tried to reinstall the certificate